# Error connecting Qt Creator to Raspberry Pi using ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, qt-creator

I have generated an image for the Raspberry Pi board using `buildroot 2014.11`, but while connecting Qt Creator via ssh to Raspberry Pi board it shows the following error:

```
Connecting to host…
SSH connection failure: SSH Protocol error: Server and client capabilities don’t match. Client list was: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc. Server list was aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com.
Device test failed.
```

The generated Raspberry Pi image uses `openssh-6.7p1`. And the host system I am using `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` and `Qt Creator 3.2.1` (opensource) based on Qt 5.3.2 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit).

For the above problem I have reported the problem to the buildroot forum, they suggested to upgrade the client list. Link for the post https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=7730

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a bug in Buildroot. On your server, you need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add this line :

```
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

Then restart the ssh daemon or reboot your RPi. See [man sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5). This works if you are using OpenSSH. If you're using Dropbear, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with my BeagleBone Black using Debian Jessie.
The problem seems to be in Qt Creator 3.2.1 that I was also using.

I've upgraded to Qt Creator 3.3.0; now all is back in order and I can connect to my BeagleBone from Qt Creator.

Hope this will help you.